# The Hyper-Modern Kidnapper: Crime Scene #2

Tags: story, visual

**The Story:**
Sergeant Vimes had been unable to get very far with the painting found at [last night's crime scene](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49978/9000) and was feeling frustrated and tired after losing so much sleep the night before. They'd already asked around at every local print shop they could find and nobody had any record of making the puzzle. Either it was from somewhere outside of the city or the kidnapper had a large format printer of his own. There were no fingerprints or even the usual printer steganography. Just as he about to head home, the call came in from another apparent kidnapping. He was told the scene was similar and they thought it could be the same perp. Sighing, Vimes picked up his notebook, shouted to Lipwig, and headed for the pool cars.

Once on the scene, a tech brought him a photographed copy of a note as well as one of the psycho's next puzzle. Before he handed them over, the tech spoke up. "Uh, Sarge? The, um... The puzzle was painted on the wall this time. It's a bunch of different colors but, uh, the red ones... They appeared to be blood so we did a quick blood test. We don't have anything definitive but it's the same blood type that was found at the other house. See, though, there's way too much of it. If it all came from the same person...I don't think..."

Vimes nodded and took the paperwork. It seemed like they had a deadline now. He read the note first and glanced at the puzzle before handing it over to Lipwig. "Alright, kid, what can your magic glasses do with this one?" The young officer had them ready and studied the picture for a few minutes, muttering to himself. Finally, he spoke up. "I think I have it, Sarge. I'm afraid it's not any more helpful than the last one, though." Vimes took the glasses, careful to not mess with any settings, and slipped them over his head.

---

**The Puzzle:**

Using the clues in the note, can you find the message hidden in the colored dots?

[image: Poem]

[image: KidnapperNumberTwo]

Comment: It's Braille - 'boxes of six'. Don't know what to do with it though

Comment: Does the solution require the reader to pronounce words with a specific accent?

Comment: @IanMacDonald The solution has some informal language in it was but it's exactly as it appears in the original lyrics (as far as I could tell, at least).

Comment: Yeah, I just mean that when puzzles say "read aloud", sometimes it requires pronunciation of vowels in locale-specific ways. For instance, "idea" rhymes with "clear" in some dialects and "mamma mia" in others.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Ah, I see. It is naught but a coincidence in this case. The instruction to close your eyes and read aloud is a clue pointing towards braille. Beastly Gerbil is right about that part.

Comment: I tried dividing the dots into an 8x7 grid of braille cells and came out with meaningless gibberish. Didn't think it'd be that easy, so there's obviously another step. I'll investigate more when I get home (didn't think this was worth posting as an answer).

Comment: @F1Krazy Rainbow falls down my oh my / Keep them in their place you knave

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is my first answer, so I hope I do this right.

Bands of three and boxes of six, as Beastly Gerbil mentioned, referred to

> Braille

The next several lines refer to a rainbow and keeping them in order, which made me think of

> the colors of the light spectrum/rainbow: ROY G BIV

If you take merge the boxes down and pick them out by color, you get a grid that looks like this:

> [image]

Which is part of the chorus from

> One Way or Another by Blondie

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, then. I'm glad you came along when you did. I was crafting up a hint because I suffer from over-eagerness to have my puzzles solved.

Comment: Nicely done! :)